# No wallpaper in 16.04

Tags: unity, upgrade, compiz, home-directory, desktop-background

Ever since I installed Ubuntu 16.04 (fresh, but kept my home directory), I've had a broken wallpaper that I cannot change (i.e. changing the wallpaper doesn't do anything). I tried resetting Unity (unit-tweak-tool --reset-unity) and resetting Compiz (dconf reset -f /org/compiz/). Now I have no wallpaper (black). Still, changing the wallpaper doesn't have any effect.

I also tried creating a new user. The new user works fine and I can change the wallpaper too. In fact, that is why I figured having kept my home directory might be the problem and reset Unity and Compiz.

Comment: Anyone? Still no wallpaper here :)

Comment: Even I have same issue with Lenovo ideapad laptop. Do let me know if you resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1) try this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

2) run nautilus

```
nautilus -n
```